# how to get the real time in windows

Tags: javascript, php, windows, time, xampp

I was build a Web system which is running on Windows and Linux too. It's running through Xampp. In this situation who using this System changing the time simply and add missed data into the system. So i want to track those. For that i was plan to get the real time using a time server.  But if that PC doesn't have Internet that will gonna be a problem to get real time. So i need something execute behind of the System which doesn't interact with Windows Time. So i can get the real time. IS there anyway to do it using VB OR Any scripting language ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the system in question doesn't have an internet connection, I don't believe there's any way to get the "real" time, just the system time.

Comment: Can't we create a bat file to execute behind the system ?

Comment: @samitha: Sure. What would it contain that would give you the real time?

Comment: only The date  :) `yy-mm-dd`

Comment: But how precise do you want it? 99.99% of the *(real or system)* time, system time is accurate for the date - it should be accurate enough within a boundary of 5 or so minutes.

Answer (score 0):

So... you want to get an accurate count of 'real time', not system time, without being connected to the internet?

The only thing I can think of is a radio frequency controlled device to correct the time - e.g. http://www.galsys.co.uk/time-receivers/

Normally, if it was connected to the internet, you could get it to read the time off of the internet - e.g. from here http://tycho.usno.navy.mil/timer.html - that could be done on a Linux system by using a bash script, `curl` or `wget`, and the `date` command.